# Most efficient way to filter out certain data from my log file with Java BufferedReader

Tags: java, performance, loops, logging, bufferedreader

With my log file it can be assumed that (almost) every line contains a test case name and the associated status "failed" or "passed".

```
timestamp | testcase-name | status | further information
1564481027 | ping | passed | device x is reachable
```

I have written a method that gives me a summary for each test case in my testcase list - see for yourself.

```
public List<TestcaseSummary> createTestcaseSummaryList(String pathToRegressionFile) throws IOException {

    testcaseSummaryList = new ArrayList<>();
    testcaseNameList = daoTestcaseName.getTestcaseList();

    //close in catch clause
    FileReader in = new FileReader(pathToRegressionFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String line;


    for (int i = 0; i < testcaseNameList.size(); i++) {

        int amount = 0;
        int passed = 0;
        int failed = 0;

        String testcaseName = testcaseNameList.get(i).getName();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains(testcaseName)) {
                if (line.contains("passed")) {
                    passed++;
                    amount++;
                } else if (line.contains("failed")) {
                    failed++;
                    amount++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (amount > 0) {
            testcaseSummaryList.add(new TestcaseSummary(testcaseName, amount, passed, failed));
        }
    }

    return testcaseSummaryList;
}
```

Currently I scan the whole file for each name. Wouldn't it be more efficient to create a summary by scanning the file just once? 
I guess the first thing I have to do is to swap the while loop with the for loop like this.

```
//scan every line just once
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < testcaseNameList.size(); i++) {
```

Now I'm unsure - should I create a new TestcaseSummary object as soon as I find a suitable name and save it in a list? How should I check whether the required TestcaseSummary object was ever created to update it constantly? 
Would this effort increase performance at all? 
I'm looking forward to your ideas.

Comment: You should really be using java.util.logging, SLF4J, Logback or some form of logging framework if you are wanting to add this kind of functionality to your program. Don't reinvent the wheel. But if you must, you'd be better of putting it all in a Stream and filtering the stream accordingly...

Comment: @DanielScarfe This questions seems to be more about parsing log files than producing logs.

Comment: @Thilo Correct.

Comment: You could probably grep this info just as quickly.

Comment: You definetly should change the logic, that the file is only read once. Each time You have read a line, do all tests for this line. Add up the results (amount, passed, failed) in a Map with `testcaseName` as key.
At the end (`br.readLine() == null`) You can create the `TestcaseSummary` for each `testcaseName` from this Map.